# Converting between Bloomberg exchange codes and MICs

Tags: market-data

Is there an (open) way to map Bloomberg's 2-letter exchange code to MIC identifiers, e.g. `UN` to `XNYS`?

Comment: I am afeared that a lookup table might be required here... but in fairness, there are not that many exchanges out there...

Answer (score 1):

I can point you to https://github.com/ga-group/bsym/blob/master/pricing_source_iso10383.ttl

Disclaimer: I created that file.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search finds [this link](https://stockmarketmba.com/globalstockexchanges.php). Looks like you can just download the CSV.

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, it is not up to date (or at least not comprehensive enough). For reference, https://bsym.bloomberg.com/api/enumValues/v2/exchCode contains 883 exchange codes (883!!).