# Exchange code used by Yahoo Finance

Tags: equities, exchange, yahoofinance

I see the following code in the exchange column of the lookup page.

https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup/

Example tickers are in the parentheses.

- ASE (ZOM) *
- BTS (CBOE) *
- NCM (ZYXI)
- NGM (ZYNE)
- NMS (ZY)
- NYQ (ZZZ) *

The ones without `*` don't seem to be found in the following exchange code lists.

https://propreports.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PR/pages/589983/Listing+Exchange+Codes

Could anybody let me know what these exchange codes mean? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting between Bloomberg exchange codes and MICs](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54477/converting-between-bloomberg-exchange-codes-and-mics)

Comment: Not really. So NCM, NGM, NMS should have X prepended? Why the X is missing?

Comment: Let's look at [Yahoo Finance](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/equity?s=ZYX) . ZYXI is the ticker symbol of Zynex, Inc in exchange "NCM". According to [Refinitiv](https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/storage/attachments/901-exchange-codes.txt)  NMS is National Market System, NGS is Nasdaq global select, NGM is Nasdaq global market, NCM is Nasdaq capital market , NYQ is Consolidated Issue listed by NYSE, PNK is US 'Other OTC' (Pink Sheets) etc. This really isn't a quant question.

Answer (score 1):

Download https://www.iso20022.org/sites/default/files/ISO10383_MIC/ISO10383_MIC.pdf from https://www.iso20022.org/market-identifier-codes . These are [ISO 10383 Market Identifier Codes (MIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_Identifier_Code). (Zoom to 500% so you can read what it says.) or look at http://www.iotafinance.com/en/ISO-10383-Market-Identification-Codes-MIC.html Look for XNCM, XASE, XNGM, etc. Note that you need to prepend X in front of Yahoo Finance's 3-letter code in order to get a MIC.